# Mongodb query (find) not returning results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

.find() is not working as expected. It's something simple and stupid I'm sure but I can't figure it out.  I have 3 documents in my collection so far.

```
Earner.find(); // returns all 3 documents

Earner.find( { year: 2019 } ) // returns nothing 
Earner.find( { year: '2019' } ) // returns nothing 
Earner.find( { year: { $eq: 2019 } } ) // returns nothing 
Earner.find( { year: { $eq: '2019' } } ) // returns nothing
```

But when I go to the Atlas console, `{ year: 2019 }` returns my matching document.
Makes no sense! Gotta be something dumb. Thanks for the help!

[image: atlas query]

Comment: What does the schema look like?

Comment: Are you in the right database?

Comment: Yeah I'm in the right database. That's the part that makes no sense. When I make a change in Atlas, I see that change coming back in my .find().   But .find( { things })  always returns nothing.

Comment: GAH! it was schema Joe!!   I had String, should have been Number. It was correct in the database, but not in the schema.  If you put that in an answer, I'm happy to accept it. Thank you!